# Schema validation difference between BizTalk IDE and XmlReader

Tags: unit-testing, validation, schema, biztalk

I'm trying to get into unit tests for a BizTalk application I'm working on, following the example in Michael Stephensons [blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20200109192352/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/michaelstephenson/archive/2008/03/30/120850.aspx) and seemed to be getting somewhere

Then I got an error down the line, which I tracked back to a "invalid" XML test file I was using, but this was passing my validation against schema unit test ...

 - *reason being incorrect namespace*

My puzzlement is why does the XmlReader think the XML is valid vs. the schema, but if I use the BizTalk IDE "Validate Instance" option I get the errors ...

... *error BEC2004: Validate Instance failed for schema FromFrontOffice.xsd, file: ...*

```
XmlSchema schema = XmlSchema.Read(schemaStream, null);
XmlReaderSettings xmlReaderSettings = new XmlReaderSettings();
xmlReaderSettings.Schemas.Add(schema);
xmlReaderSettings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
xmlReaderSettings.ValidationEventHandler += ValidationEventHandler;
XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(xmlStream, xmlReaderSettings);
while (xmlReader.Read())

private void ValidationEventHandler(object sender, ValidationEventArgs args)
{
  if (args.Exception == null) return;
  _IsValid = false;
}
```

Comment: What does your schema and your instance document look like?

Comment: What version of BizTalk are you using?  Typically BizTalk schema validation is performed differently (using BizTalk libraries) so that may give you different results than the standard .NET ways of validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think I've sorted it ... trick seems to be using ValidationFlags

```
xmlReaderSettings.ValidationFlags =
    XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings |
    XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessIdentityConstraints |
    XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessInlineSchema |
    XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessSchemaLocation;
```